# E-mail sent from thunderbird not opening up

Tags: 12.04, thunderbird, email

I have thunderbird installed in my 12.04 version. Whenever i forward any e-mail from my inbox it gets forwarded as a .eml attachment. How can i prevent this from happening, or alternatively how can i read .eml format files in mail???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within thunderbird select edit/preferences/composition.

Change the Forward message option from as attachment to inline.

Then for good measure you could select edit/account settings/composition and addressing to choose the layout (reply at top etc)

Hope this helps

Comment: yeah, it helped.. Thanks.. but how to open that .eml file, it try opening it up and it displays the content in a weird manner

Answer (score 1):

**Edit based on comment**

Unfortunately Gmail doesn’t support .eml files. Below is a Google group question.

[.eml files in gmail](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/_K9YqnJcIVE)

What I do it that situation is forward them to an email account I have setup in Thunderbird.

**Original Answer**

How to open.eml file with Thunderbird ?

You can set it as the default application to open .eml files

1. Right click on the file -> Properties
2. Click the Open With tab.
3. Select Thunderbird from the list.
4. Make sure to click the Set as Default button.

On my system I can double click .eml files and Thunderbird opens them correctly.

Hope that helps

Comment: i have forwarded them to my gmail account and was trying to open them in firefox/gmail